# Risks of one-hot encoding with drop_first=True for correlations

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn, one-hot-encoding

I am starting to learn the KNN algorithm/method. One of the things I came across was one-hot encoding for categorical features and it makes sense. But, what I saw on a couple of occasions is that the first encountered category was dropped and then the columns were analyzed to check correlation with the target variable to select features of interest.

My question is: by using `drop_first=True`, are we not risking losing a category of high correlation?

For example I have a feature called 'marital status' that has three values and I am analyzing if the person took a bank loan:

| marital_status |
| --- |
| single |
| divorced |
| married |

What if most of divorced participants who were men took out a loan but because it was the first encountered category it was dropped? Now I won't be able to see it in my correlations heat map. Additionally, the model would perform quite differently based on which category it encounters first. So wouldn't it be wiser to keep the default state (i.e., `drop_first=False`)?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what you said. If you want to look at the correlation heap map then I wouldn't drop it for sure.
For the model training instead, it depends on the model. Also, it depends if you'll have other unexpected categories that you will handle at prediction time without raising an error, because then the one hot encoding "0-0" will be used for both "single" and eventual unexpected categories.

I see the `drop_first=True` more useful when you have just 2 categories, where having 2 one-hot-encoded features is redundant.